# How to allow webcam access in Chrome kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, kiosk-mode

On Ubuntu, I'm launching Chrome like so:

`google-chrome --kiosk http://foo.com`

When I try to access the webcam, the user is not prompted. It silently fails.